# Slide between image view in recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I want to make story like instagram stories. First I've created a horizontal recycle view and now I want to slide between views in recycle after clicking on that view was choosed. Is it a good idea to use view pager to slide and make animation?

Comment: It does already scrolls because of `RecyclerView`. Check this source: https://github.com/abdl-slm/horizontal_recycler_view the only thing it needs is a `CircleImageView` & animations on items of course.

Comment: @Mohsen Of Course! If you notice I said want to make it like instagram. Means that by clicking on one item it should go to new activity and show full screen of story. I need slide in new activity.

Comment: Oh now i get it. Well yeah, `ViewPager` is a good options for that but you can also use `Fragment`s. You may want to take a look: [StoriesProgressView](https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView) & [FragmentAnimations](https://github.com/kakajika/FragmentAnimations)